# How to remove Home Gallery from Windows 11 Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11

I want this section removed from Windows 11 Explorer:
[image: Explorer Home Gallery section]

The registry method to remove the key on `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_41040327]` did not work for me. This method was mentioned on some websites.

I couldn't find any similar question asked about this on Superuser.

There's no option to hide this section:

[image: No option]

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but maybe its good enough? There's a program on github called ExplorerPatcher, with this tool, you can finally undo Microsoft's changes to explorer, and run explorer from windows 10 or windows 7, including making adjustments to the taskbar and other things Explorer does. I haven't tested this, but maybe it will also remove these when you set it to Windows 10 mode.

Comment: @LPChip: ExplorerPatcher can really mess up Windows. It's better not to recommend it.

Comment: @Shayan: The registry key that is recommended for deletion is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_41040327\{e88865ea-0e1c-4e20-9aa6-edcd0212c87c}`. Can you check if it has come back. ([link](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-remove-gallery-from-file-explorer.html))

Comment: @harrymc I find it a really good tool. How can it mess up Windows? Asking out of curiosity

Comment: @LPChip: I answered a couple of posts here where ExplorerPatcher messed up their Explorer display, for which nobody managed to find a fix. I don't remember whether Repair Install was enough, but in at least one case the poster reinstalled Windows.

Comment: @harrymc I see. Maybe there was a buggy release, seems very stable in latest releases.

Comment: @LPChip: I think it's mostly Windows Update that messes up the ExplorerPatcher patches.

Comment: @harrymc so far, haven't had an issue with them. But we'll see. For now I'll not recommend ExplorerPatcher.

Comment: @harrymc I can confirm that the key you provided does actually remove Gallery. But not Home. So I guess I'm halfway there! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article
[How to Remove Gallery from File Explorer on Windows 11?](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-remove-gallery-from-file-explorer.html)

To remove Gallery requires removing this registry key using
`regedit`:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_41040327{e88865ea-0e1c-4e20-9aa6-edcd0212c87c}

Or in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) :

```
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_41040327\{e88865ea-0e1c-4e20-9aa6-edcd0212c87c}
```

---

From [Add or Remove Home in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-home-in-navigation-pane-of-file-explorer-in-windows-11.2449/):

The following `.reg` file will remove it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"HubMode"=dword:00000001

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489\{f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}]
```

This will remove Home in the Navigation Pane of Explorer,
except in Common Dialog Boxes. To remove it everywhere
requires taking ownership over a registry key, and is
detailed in the article.